# dividing a multiply imputed dataset into derivation and validation cohorts

Tags: predictive-models, multiple-imputation

R/statistics noob. Mac OSX 10.11, RStudio 0.99.842.

I'm developing a clinical prediction tool as part of my PhD. I have missing data (23k cases, 24 variables, 70% of variables have at least one missing observation, 45% of samples/cases have at least one missing observation, 4.4% of observations are missing) and have imputed missing values using MICE (45 imputations, 1 for each 1% missing, 25 iterations).

I have a few queries about how I go about dividing the imputed dataset into derivation and validation subsets.

Should I have divided the original dataset into derivation and validation cohorts then imputed missing data as separate imputations? I believe it is best to impute with as large a dataset as possible thus impute original data then split imputed dataset into derivation and validation cohorts.

If this latter approach is correct, do I need to ensure that each patients data (original and imputed) goes into one or other of the derivation or validation subsets i.e. if patientX has 5 imputed datasets should all the imputed data go into one of derivation or validation subsets or can the imputed data be spread between derivation and validation cohorts?

Lastly, any pointers as to how this might be achieved? MICE contains tools for combining imputed datasets, but I've not found anything to enable extraction by particular cases (e.g each patient has a unique identifier to enable extraction into a derivation or validation subset).

My initial thoughts are to stick with single imputed dataset, randomly divide the original original dataset into derivation and validation subsets, use those patient identification numbers to extract from the multiply imputed dataset.

Not sure if this is correct approach, so any insight greatly appreciated.

mike

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I used the 'complete' function to build the 'complete' table of all imputations. I divided the complete table into derivation and validation datasets utilising patientID numbers and thereafter converted the two datasets back to mids objects.